# How to assign a hadoop command to a variable in unix script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to assign the result of a hadoop command in a variable in unix shell script.

This is the code I am using but it is giving me error.

```
cat ${AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP}/${BBCA_HDFS_Config_File} 
while read line
do
        hdfs_path="$line"
        echo ${hdfs_path}
        hdfs dfs -ls ${hdfs_path} 
        
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
                write_log "hdfs directory exist"
        
                hdfs dfs -ls ${hdfs_path} | while read line
                do
                        echo ${line}
                        hdfs_create_datetime=`hadoop fs -stat "%y" ${line}`
                done
        else 
                write_log "hdfs directory does not exist. Please check."
        fi
done < ${AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP}/${BBCA_HDFS_Config_File}
```

Can anyone help if I am using the command correctly.

Comment: `This is the code i am using but it is giving me error.` And what is the error?

Comment: `hdfs_create_datetime=\`hadoop fs -stat "%y" ${line}\`` does "assign a variable"., but `hdfs_create_datetime=$(hadoop fs -stat "%y" $line)` would look cleaner